# Get selected rows value from kartik gridView in modal and pass it to parent form

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

I try to get value from modal bootstrap (contain table kartik gridview), and i want to pass the selected value to parent form (action create form). How to do that? Please advice.
modal form contains fields like this

```
<?php
$gridColumns = [        
    'id',
    'date',
    [
        'attribute' => 'agen_id',
        'value' => 'agen.agen_name'
    ],
    [
        'attribute' => 'price', 
        'format' => ['decimal', 0],            
    ],
    'remark_1:ntext',
    'remark_2:ntext',

] ?>
```

and this is the button in parent form

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="form-group field-poagen-price"> 
        <br>
        <?= Html::button('Price List', ['value' => Url::to('../pricelist/list'), 'class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'BtnModalPriceList']) ?>
        <?php 
            Modal::begin([
                    'header' => 'List Harga',
                    'id' => 'modal',
                    'size' => 'modal-md'
                ]);
            echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";
            Modal::end();
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and i register my jquery like this

```
$('#BtnModalPriceList').click(function(){
$('#modal').modal('show')
    .find('#modalContent')
    .load($(this).attr('value'));});
```

I want to get the value from modal to pass to the parent in order to fill the required field.
I have searched for a few days and still have no luck.
Please advice for the master. Thanks before.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by saying `selected rows`? Are you using checkbox or something?

Comment: I want to use hyperlink or button is ok. Do not want to use checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. This is what i do.
Create custom button in the gridView

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'template' => '{select}',
    'buttons' => [
        'select' => function($url, $model, $key){
            return Html::button('Select', [
                'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Select'),
                'aria-label' => Yii::t('yii', 'Select'),                        
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary select-row',
                'data-id' => $model->id,
            ]);
        },
    ],            
],
```

and then register to jquery to process the data

```
$(document).on('click', '.select-row', function(){
    // get id from custom button
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.get('../pricelist/get-price', {id : id}, function(data){            
            $('#poagen-price').val(data);
        });
        $('#modalPriceList').modal('hide');
        $('#poagen-fee').focus();
});
```

got help from @milos-ozegovic